# creating a autocomplete combobox or dropdownlist using jquery components

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

i am working in asp.net mvc 3 web application which uses razor code.

and am in the process of creation of an autocomplete combobox or dropdownlist using jquery components in this application

can any one guide me in getting this done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a autocomplete combobox in asp.netmvc 3  razor web application with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090916/how-to-create-a-autocomplete-combobox-in-asp-netmvc-3-razor-web-application-wit)

Comment: that question has been closed.i was not able to reopen the question .so i have edited and posted the question with details

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far. Search before you ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can checkout this library

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/